# Custom post registered in plugin is redirecting to index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress

I have run into a weird situation, which ever post type i am registering in my plugin is working just fine except showing on front end, when i click on view post, it shows the correct url of the post but actually redirects me to index page

**More Info**

The same post type when registered in theme's functions.php is working just fine as we would expect it to.

**P.S**

1. I dont have anything in .htaccess.
2. I am using [**wordpress plugin boilerplate**](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) to build my plugin

Comment: can you share the register post type code?

Comment: save code which is there on register_post_type page of codex .. that also is not working